# Add additional empty attribute to existing HTML element

Tags: php, wordpress, analytics, matomo, event-tracking

I try to include content tracking to a site with the Matomo Tagmanager. According to their [documentation](https://developer.matomo.org/guides/content-tracking) this should be in the form of

```
<a href="/random" class="tfs-highlight-button" 
 data-track-content 
 data-content-name="Random click" 
 data-content-piece="Random newsletter">
Click for random
</a>
```

I want to add this through my functions.php with the following code

```
add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', function ( $atts, $item, $args ) {
if ( 'tfs-highlight-button' === $item->classes[0] ) {
    $atts['data-track-content'] ;
    $atts['data-content-name']="Random click";
    $atts['data-content-piece']="Random newsletter";
 }
 return $atts; 
}, 10, 3 );
```

Unfortunately the attribute data-track-content isn't added to the HTML element. How do I add an "empty" data-attribute to the element? I already tried $atts['data-track-content']='' and $atts['data-track-content']=NULL but this didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress removes empty/falsy attributes. I would do something like this:

```php
add_filter('nav_menu_link_attributes', function ($atts, $item, $args) {
  if (in_array('tfs-highlight-button', $item->classes)) {
    $atts['data-track-content'] = '1';
    $atts['data-content-name'] = 'Random click';
    $atts['data-content-piece'] = 'Random newsletter';
  }

  return $atts;
}, 10, 3);

add_filter('walker_nav_menu_start_el', function($item_output, $item) {
  if (in_array('tfs-highlight-button', $item->classes)) {
    $item_output = str_replace('data-track-content="1"', 'data-track-content', $item_output);
  }

  return $item_output;
}, 10, 2);
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried it but this makes the output 

```<a href="/random" class="tfs-highlight-button" 
 data-track-content="" 
 data-content-name="Random click" 
 data-content-piece="Random newsletter">
Click for random
</a>```